# Front-end phtml template form doesn't connect to controller.php file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

The web system which I'm working on right now, has a add.phtml (in views folder) form, which contain normal form elements and pageController.php (in Controller folder) file which has function to be connected when user hit "add page" button on the form. The codes goes like this.

on **add.phtml** file,

input type = "submit" value ="Add Page"

on **pageController.php** file,

function insertAction(){

}

For some reason these two doesn't connect now. Is anybody have any idea why this doesn't work or what should I check on this kind of a problem. The web system on zend framewok. I really appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Google for Zend beginning tutorials.

Essentially your pageController is looking for a phtml file in 
views/scripts/page (note page is the same name as the 'page' in pageController) directory and is expecting a phtml file insert.phtml, this file's root name corresponds to the action defined in the controller, see insertAction.

sic.

```
    class doodahController extends Zend_Controller{

public function campdownAction(){
}
//..more stuff
}


Directory structure
application
  controllers
    doodahController
  views
    scripts
      doodah
       campdown.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes, I do have addAction() function in my pageController.php file and that connects too and fine. But what I need is when user hit the 'add page' button it should call the insrtAction() function. The same setup works for update process. This was working before and some reason it doesn't work now. Please help me!